# Assets\fps\scripts\Loading screen.cs(18,11): error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'bool'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class Loadingscreen : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject LOADING;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        LOADING.SetActive(false);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
       if(SceneManager.LoadScene("SampleScene")) 
       {
            LOADING.SetActive(true);
       }
    }
}
```

this is my code and i dont know whats the problem i tried to solve it but it did not work
i really have no clue what it could be

Comment: Which line produces the error.  Is it this one?:  `if(SceneManager.LoadScene("SampleScene"))`  If so, it sounds like `SceneManager.LoadScene("SampleScene")` doesn't return anything, so you can't use it in an `if` statement.  What are you expecting it to return and why?  What are you trying to accomplish in this method?

Comment: if the scene switches the Loading screen(LOADING) should pop up its an ui image

Comment: Well, as stated, [`LoadScene`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadScene.html) doesn't return anything.  If you want to monitor if/when the scene changes, perhaps you want the [`activeSceneChanged` event](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager-activeSceneChanged.html)?

Comment: i tried `if(SceneManager.activeSceneChanged += ChangedActiveScene)` but it does not work

Comment: Why would you try that exact syntax?  What are you expecting that to do and why?  Honestly, it sounds like you're just randomly copying and pasting anything you find on the internet and hoping for the best.  This won't work.  Take some time to start with some tutorials on the C# language, on Unity specifically, etc.  Carefully examine and try to understand the example provided in the linked documentation.  Make an attempt that involves more effort than just copying and pasting whatever is the first thing you see.

Comment: i watched a lot of tutorials and i mean alot and the most scripts in my game are from me but i dont know how to solve this the most other errors were easy to solve not all but the most but i dont get what unity wants from me

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

i solved it the code is now

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class Loadingscreen : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject LOADING;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        LOADING.SetActive(false);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name == "SampleScene")
        {
            LOADING.SetActive(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).